# My aggregate is not affected by ROLLUP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN (GROUPING(Name) = 1) THEN 'All' ELSE Name END AS Name, 
        CASE WHEN (GROUPING(Type) = 1) THEN 'All' ELSE Type END AS Type,
        sum(quantity) AS [Quantity],
        CAST(sum(quantity) * (SELECT QuantityMultiplier FROM QuantityMultipliers WHERE a = t.b) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Multiplied Quantity
FROM @Table t
GROUP BY Name, Type WITH ROLLUP
```

I'm trying to return a list of Names, Types, a summed Quantity and a summed quantity multiplied by an arbitrary number. All fine so far. I also need to return a sub-total row per Name and per Type, such as the following

```
Name        Type        Quantity        Multiplied Quantity
-------     ---------   -----------     -------------------
a           1           2               4
a           2           3               3
a           ALL         5               7
b           1           6               12
b           2           1               1
b           ALL         7               13
ALL         ALL         24              40
```

The first 3 columns are fine. I'm getting null values in the rollup rows for the multiplied quantity though. The only reason I can think this is happening is because SQL doesn't recognize the last column as an aggregate now that I've multiplied it by something.

Can I somehow work around this without things getting too convoluted?

I will be falling back onto temporary tables if this can't be done.

Comment: I think, `t.b` should either be mentioned in GROUP BY or be inside an aggregate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sub-query to acquire the multiplier, you have `WHERE a=b`. Are either `a` or `b` from the tables in your main query?

If these values are static (nothing to do with the main query), it looks like it should be fine...

If the `a` or `b` values are the `name` or `type` field, they can be `NULL` for the rollup records.  If so, you can change to something similiar to...

`CAST(sum(quantity * (<multiplie_query>)) AS DECIMAL(18,2))`.

If `a` or `b` are other field from your main query, you'd be getting multiple records back, not just a single multiplier.  You could change to something like...

`CAST(sum(quantity) * (SELECT MAX(multiplier) FROM ...)) AS DECIMAL(18,2))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the sub-query does rely on a field from the main query, that should have been more clear. I'll try what you said.

Comment: No luck using `MAX` on `Multiplier` unfortunately, still getting nulls in that column for the rollup record.

Comment: I'm off home now, but as a debugging excercise I'd suggest taking each seperate component and outputting it as a seperate field.  Basically, see what the different multiplier queries give on their own.